# Need a simulation of a lost recording related to a murder mystery game realted to the murder on former UN secretary

Tags: roleplaying, adventure-writing, investigation, adventure-path

I'm a scout leader in Sweden and I'm preparing a murder mystery for my scouts. We prepare simulated tasks for them so that they gain more intel so that they can solve the mystery of the death of Dag Hammarskjöld. The war pilot who presumably shot Dag Hammarskjölds plane down recorded some words after he had done it, but the recording is lost, so I need someone to recreate it. These are the spoken words:

“I see a transport plane coming low,” “All the lights are on. I’m going to go down to make a run on it. Yes, it’s the Transair DC6. It’s the plane. I’ve hit it. There are flames. It’s going down. It’s crashing.”

The recording must be old-sounding and slightly diffuse (this takes place in the 60s). It is spoken in English, but it would be really nice with a belgian/flemish accent on it. French or german accents works too. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about tabletop or free-form RPGs. Instead, it is asking for help to produce a prop.

Comment: This is a really cool request -- but completely not what we're able to help with on this site.  Good luck getting what you need!

Comment: If you're researching the actual events, this sounds like a request for [aviation.se].